# What is the "clean way" to align multiple floating spans with different font-sizes?

Tags: css, css-float, html

I have three span **with different font sizes**, which are wrapped in a `div` with different floats.

I tried to align these `spans` correctly by adjusting the `line-height`, but it seems a little bit hacky to me, as the last floating `span` is overflowing the container with this method.

I tried to play with `vertical-align` without luck.

So what would be the *clean way* to align these, without hacking (if possible)?

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/s8CeD/3/), and here is the code :

### HTML

```
<div class="comTitle">
    <span class="comUserName">admin</span>
    <span class="comUserRank"> - Animator</span>
    <span class="timeCreated">The 13/03/13 at 16:49</span>
</div>
```

---

### CSS

```
.comTitle {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    /*line-height:22px;*/
}

.comUserName {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #444;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    clear:left;
}

.comUserRank {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: grey;
    clear:left;
}

.timeCreated {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444;
    float: right;
    /*vertical-align:baseline;*/
    /*line-height:26px;*/
}
```

**[Edit]** I know how to deal with `position` property, and I can make this aligned right with :

```
.timeCreated {
    ...
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -4px;
}
```

Or absolute positioning, but I'd like to know if there is a possibility to **align the last span to the baseline (instead of the top) of the wrapper** without changing the flow of the elements?

Comment: Do you need to use float or can you use display inline or inline-block? If you can do the latter you can make use of vertical-align.

Comment: `Float:right` always causes me these kinds of problems. I tend to try and use `position: absolute` instead where possible.

Comment: @dsundy, @gaynorvader I want my last span to be at the right of its container without changing `position` (see edited question)

Comment: I think what you're asking is if it is possible to align the text after floating automatically. As far as I know this is not possible without using javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add some `padding-top` space to the `.timeCreated` span - the difference of the font-size (4px)

```css
.timeCreated {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
```

And [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gguy3/3/)

Comment: I'll use padding for now, I'll accept your solution when I'll be sure there isn't another solution

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how clean this is but it works, I just gave it some positioning. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/s8CeD/2/)

```
.comTitle {
font-family:'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
/*line-height:22px;*/
position:relative;
}
.comUserName {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 16px;
color: #444;
font-variant: small-caps;
clear:left;
}
.comUserRank {
font-size: 12px;
font-style: italic;
color: grey;
clear:left;
}
.timeCreated {
font-style: italic;
font-size: 12px;
color: #444;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more explicit in my question. I know how to deal with it with absolute / relative positioning, but I'd like to know if it's possible to align these span without breaking the flow of the elements (see my edited question)